# How can I modify a C-style array as D-style array?

Tags: arrays, memory-management, d, shared-memory, slice

### Question

**What's the optimal way to accept a C-style array as a parameter, modify it as a D-style array (including changing the length), and return it as a C-style array?**

---

### In Context

I'm writing a **library in D, which compiles to a DLL with a C interface** (I'll be calling my D DLL from C++, so the C interface is necessary).
**It takes `byte` arrays and modifies their contents, sometimes changing the array length**.

Because I'm using the C interface, my functions have to accept arrays as C-style. Ideally, I'd like to be able to to allocate more memory (ie. extend `bufferMaxSize`) if the given buffer is too small.

This is how my D DLL accepts parameters right now:

```d
// D library code; compiles to DLL with C interface.
// bufferSize is the data length, and is a pointer because I may modify the data length.
// bufferMaxSize is the total allocated buffer size.
export extern(C) void patchData(const size_t bufferMaxSize, size_t * bufferSize, byte * buffer) { ... }
```

In my D library, I have existing code that accepts D-style arrays. **Somewhere along the line, there has to be a conversion of the C-style array to D-style array**.

I'm currently doing the conversion like this (simplified example):

```d
// D library code; compiles to DLL with C interface.
export extern(C) void patchData(const size_t bufferMaxSize, size_t * bufferSize, byte * buffer) {
    // Convert from C-style array to D-style.
    byte[] dStyleArray = buffer[0 .. *bufferSize];

    // Modify data.
    dStyleArray[0] = cast(byte) 0xab;
    dStyleArray[1] = cast(byte) 0xbc;

    dStyleArray.length = dStyleArray.length + 16;

    // Return modified data as C-style array.
    buffer[0 .. dStyleArray.length] = dStyleArray[0 .. dStyleArray.length];
    *bufferSize = dStyleArray.length;
}
```

It works, but I'm unsure of what's really happening here. My main concern is speed. If I'm looping over this function, **I don't want to be constantly allocating new memory and copying its contents back and forth**.

When I do `byte[] dStyleArray = buffer[0 .. *bufferSize]`, is D allocating a new chunk of memory and copying everything into the D-style array, or is it pointing to the already-allocated C-style array?

What's going on when I do `dStyleArray.length = dStyleArray.length + 16`? Since `dStyleArray` was sliced from `buffer`, am I allocating new memory/copying memory now? Or did I extend into `buffer`?

When I do `buffer[0 .. dStyleArray.length] = dStyleArray[0 .. dStyleArray.length];`, I *am* copying memory, right?

Is it possible to just "bind" a D-style array to a C-style array, and access pre-allocated memory through the D-style array's interface?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When I do byte[] dStyleArray = buffer[0 .. *bufferSize], is D allocating a new chunk of memory and copying everything into the D-style array, or is it pointing to the already-allocated C-style array?

It is just pointing to it. The slice operator on the right hand side is the same (conceptually) as `array.pointer = &first_element; array._length = length;` - a very quick and simple operation. (I called it `_length` instead of `length` btw because setting length property actually may call a function, that's next.)

> What's going on when I do dStyleArray.length = dStyleArray.length + 16?

That will allocate new memory. When length is extended, unless the runtime can prove it is safe (or you tell it to assume it is and it knows it came from the GC), the array is copied to a new location. It basically calls `realloc()` on the pointer - though not literally, it isn't compatible with C realloc.

Since it came from C, the runtime just knows it doesn't own the memory, that it is managed elsewhere somehow, and will always allocate a new one when trying to extend. If you want to extend by some other means, you need to do it yourself.

> When I do buffer[0 .. dStyleArray.length] = dStyleArray[0 .. dStyleArray.length];, I am copying memory, right?

right, that does copy because you sliced on the left hand side.

> Is it possible to just "bind" a D-style array to a C-style array, and access pre-allocated memory through the D-style array's interface?

The plain right hand slice:

`auto d_array = c_array[0 .. c_array_length];`

handles it for everything except length extensions. It keeps the pointer so writing to elements will instantly affect the original thing. (BTW since it is shared C memory, make sure you don't `free` it while D is still using it! You should be fine as long as you only use it inside this one function though, without storing the slice anywhere.)

If you do need to extend the length, you need to do it yourself. The way I like to do it is to slice the whole potential array, full capacity, then slice that again to get a limited capacity window.

So like maybe:

```
auto whole_array = buffer[0 .. bufferMaxSize]; // assuming buffer is already fully allocated on the C side
auto part_youre_using = whole_array[0 .. *bufferSize];

// to extend:
*bufferSize += 16; // extend the size
part_your_using = whole_array[0 .. *bufferSize]; // and reslice from the original
```

The reason I made the whole_array thing instead of reslicing `buffer` is so D can catch bounds violations for me. It doesn't do that on a naked pointer, but does on a sliced pointer since it knows the max size as its length.

If you need to extend the buffer though, do it with the right C function, like `realloc` or whatever, then slice out the whole_array and part_youre_using again.

Comment: The slicing example gave me an idea. What if I sliced the entire thing, like this: `byte[] dStyleArray = buffer[0 .. bufferMaxSize]`, and then downsized it like this: `dStyleArray.length = *bufferSize`? A full slice will allow me to change `dSyleArray.length` (within `bufferMaxSize`) without allocating new memory?

Comment: If `*bufferSize <= bufferMaxSize`, it won't allocate, as it would be the equivalent of `dStyleArray = dStyleArray[0 .. *bufferSize];`. 
You might want to favor the slicing syntax, as it will throw an `ArrayOutOfBoundException` if `*bufferSize > bufferMaxSize`, so there's no way you can reallocate whit this syntax (and that allow you to make the function `@nogc`).

Comment: Appending a foreign slice will always allocate because the runtime assumes anything beyond the current length might be gone. (With GC arrays, it can sometimes prove otherwise - it knows the capacity because it can ask the gc - butit is still conservative). So don't try to change length or use the append operator on a slice if you never want it to allocate a new copy.

Answer (score 5):

> When I do byte[] dStyleArray = buffer[0 .. *bufferSize], is D allocating a new chunk of memory and copying everything into the D-style array, or is it pointing to the already-allocated C-style array?

It's pointing. Phobos use the same trick to convert a C "string" to a D one:
https://github.com/D-Programming-Language/phobos/blob/67c95e6de21d5d627e3c57128b4d6e332c82f785/std/string.d#L208-L211

> What's going on when I do dStyleArray.length = dStyleArray.length + 16? Since dStyleArray was sliced from buffer, am I allocating new memory/copying memory now? Or did I extend into buffer?

That's probably not doing what you want / expect. It will allocate a new block on *garbage collected* memory, and copy the content to it. There is no way it can extend it because the runtime doesn't have any information about the block of memory (it is not managing it). Are you really looking to extend the buffer, or to move the pointer (which would be slicing in D) ?

> When I do buffer[0 .. dStyleArray.length] = dStyleArray[0 .. dStyleArray.length];, I am copying memory, right?

Yes. That's lowered to a memcpy.

> Is it possible to just "bind" a D-style array to a C-style array, and access pre-allocated memory through the D-style array's interface?

Yes, that's what you did at the beginning ;)

If you just want to change the first 2 elements of the array, just do the binding and change them, it will "just work".

If you want to test the behaviour, I'd recommend you put an `unittest` block below the function, so you can test what happens by giving it a pointer. Also, if you want to make sure you are not doing any GC allocation, you might want to consider putting `@nogc` on your function to statically check for that (and `nothrow` is usually a good idea as well for C function).

Answer (score 4):

Going over your code:

```
byte[] dStyleArray = buffer[0 .. *bufferSize];
```

This looks good. Note that this will not allocate memory. D arrays are essentially a pointer and a length, so this line is equivalent to this **pseudocode**:

```
struct DByteArray { byte* ptr; size_t length; }
DByteArray dStyleArray;
dStyleArray.ptr = buffer;
dStyleArray.length = *bufferSize;
```

From here on, accessing the elements of `dStyleArray` will access the same data pointed to by `buffer`, meaning that:

```
dStyleArray[0] = cast(byte) 0xab;
dStyleArray[1] = cast(byte) 0xbc;
```

will "modify `buffer`" too.

Going further:

```
dStyleArray.length = dStyleArray.length + 16;
```

Increasing `length` of a D dynamic array will cause a reallocation. The D runtime here will take the memory sliced by `dStyleArray`, and copy it to a newly-allocated memory block. If you want to make `dStyleArray` point to the first `byte` but with a longer `length`, you have to slice the pointer again:

```
dStyleArray = dStyleArray.ptr[0 .. dStyleArray.length + 16];
```

or:

```
dStyleArray = buffer[0 .. *bufferSize + 16];
```

Then, the line:

```
buffer[0 .. dStyleArray.length] = dStyleArray[0 .. dStyleArray.length];
```

(which does copy memory as you guessed) becomes redundant because the two point to the same block of memory.

> Is it possible to just "bind" a D-style array to a C-style array, and access pre-allocated memory through the D-style array's interface?

Yep, that's exactly what slicing a pointer does.